# i varible cannot be resolved to a variable

Tags: java, matrix, addition

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class high{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        int[][]arr1={{10,20,40}, {5,40,60}};
        int[][]arr2={{8,40,20} , {5,4,10}};             
        int[][]result={{0,0,0} ,  {0,0,0}}; 

        for(int i=0;i<arr1.length;i++){
            for(int j=0;j<arr[i];j++){
                resilt[i][j]=arr1[i][j]+arr2[i][j]; 
            }    
        }   
 
        for(i=0;i<arr1.length;i++){
            for(j=0;j<arr1[i];j++){
             System.out.print(result[i][j]);
            }
        }
        System.out.println(" ");
        }
    }
}
```

while executing it throws i varible cannot be resolved to a varible can anyone please in here

Comment: A little bit less of "enter code here" would improve the readability of this question a lot.

Comment: What is "resilt" (sic)?

Comment: You need to declare `i` and `j` in the second nested loop as well.  The scopes of the first `i` and `j` are confined to the loop.

Comment: Also, you have multiple typos. 1) on `j<arr[i]` in your second loop. Should either be `arr1` or `arr2`. 2) As mentioned - `resilt`. 3) There seems to be one `}` too much. Not to mention that your inner loop conditions are incorrect.

Comment: What is your use case? What do you want to achieve with this?

Comment: The sample code is not a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) due to the typos. Also, the question is a duplicate many times over (try searching SO for the exact error message, as per [site guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)).

Answer (score 1):

**Problem**
This is your first loop

```java
for(int i=0;i<arr1.length;i++){ // i declaration
    for(int j=0;j<arr[i];j++){ // j declaration
        resilt[i][j]=arr1[i][j]+arr2[i][j]; 
    } // j end of life
} // i end of life
```

After this loop both i and j does not "exist" anymore.
The compiler does not consider those name are valid as they are declared in the for block.
This is your next loop

```java
for(i=0;i<arr1.length;i++){
    for(j=0;j<arr1[i];j++){
        System.out.print(result[i][j]);
    }
}
```

Both i and j does not exist and throw a compiler erroras they cannot be resolved to variable.

**Solution**
You need to declare these new variables

```java
// Second loop
for(int i=0;i<arr1.length;i++){
    for(int j=0;j<arr1[i];j++){
        System.out.print(result[i][j]);
    }
}
```

You might also declare both variables before your loops like

```java
int i,j;

for(i=0; ...) {...} // First loop
for(i=0; ...) {...} // Second loop
```